How do I enable a PHP extension on GitLab CI?
I'm trying to use Drupal.org's GitLab CI to test a module that has a dependency on a package that requires PHP's ext-sodium to be installed:
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-sodium * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
  Problem 2
    - kreait/firebase-php[7.0.0, ..., 7.0.3] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.2.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.2.1, ..., 4.4.x-dev].
    - kreait/firebase-php[7.1.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.3.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev, 5.0.0, ..., 5.4.x-dev].
    - lcobucci/jwt[4.2.1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, 5.0.0, ..., 5.4.x-dev] require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - Root composer.json requires kreait/firebase-php ^7 -> satisfiable by kreait/firebase-php[7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/php-cli.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

source pipeline
I tried adding ext-sodium to the module's composer.json:
  "require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "ext-sodium": "*",
    "kreait/firebase-php": "^7"
  },

But that doesn't help; I'm still getting the same error.
What's the proper approach to ensure that a PHP extension is enabled on Drupal.org's GitLab CI?
Update: It seems libsodium is uniquely a pain because it is now incorporated into PHP8.1.  Issue here.

There is official documentation for adding extensions.
In .gitlab-ci.yml:
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $PHPIZE_DEPS
    - pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

This line apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $PHPIZE_DEPS is necessary because of the removal of some tooling from the Drupal GitLab CI images.
However, this won't work to install ext-sodium, because that is already bundled with PHP and can't be installed through pecl or docker-php-ext-enable on PHP 8.1+.

Adding to composer won't do - as the extension has to be available on the docker image thats building it.
in your gitlab-ci.yml
(https://git.drupalcode.org/project/firebase_php/-/blob/1.0.x/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads)
look in to running a before script ... aka
before_script: 
 - apt-get update 
 - apt-get install libsodium13


see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598594/gitlab-php-docker-image-the-requested-php-extension-gd-is-missing-from-your-sy
for more
